# Clerk jwt authentication

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, clerk

I have a React application that talks to a Django API and it uses a JWT token to authenticate requests. I wanna use Clerk to authenticate users on the frontend but I don't know how I'll get the JWT token to authenticate the requests to the backend API, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The following is what the front-end code would look like:

```js
import { useAuth } from "@clerk/clerk-react"

function App() {
  const { getToken } = useAuth();

  const sendRequest = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(
      api_url,
      {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${await getToken()}` },
      },
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }
  ...
}
```

The following is an example of authentication on the back-end (using FastAPI).

```py
import requests
import jwt
from jwt.algorithms import RSAAlgorithm
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, HTTPException
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware


@app.get("/")
async def root(request: Request):
    auth_header = request.headers.get("Authorization")

    try:
        user_id = validate_token(auth_header)
    except AuthenticationException as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=str(e))

    print(f"{user_id = }")
    return {"user": user_id}


def validate_token(auth_header: str) -> str:
    """
    returns user_id if valid
    raises AuthenticationException otherwise
    """
    try:
        token = auth_header.split(" ")[1]
    except (AttributeError, KeyError):
        raise AuthenticationException("No authentication token provided")

    jwks = requests.get(
        "https://api.clerk.com/v1/jwks",
        headers={
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {CLERK_SECRET_KEY}",
        },
    ).json()
    public_key = RSAAlgorithm.from_jwk(jwks["keys"][0])
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(
            token,
            public_key,
            algorithms=["RS256"],
            options={"verify_signature": True},
        )
    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        raise AuthenticationException("Token has expired.")
    except jwt.DecodeError:
        raise AuthenticationException("Token decode error.")
    except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
        raise AuthenticationException("Invalid token.")
    user_id = payload.get("sub")
    return user_id
```

Make sure you replace `CLERK_SECRET_KEY` with your secret key.